# Delete SharePoint Online site collections using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, sharepoint-online

I have been trying to delete site collections from a csv, I'm trying to use a powershell script to get the site URLs to be deleted.

I've tried everything, now that I've run out of ideas I'm opening this question. I'm accepting possibilities other than Powershell

PS: I'm trying to do this without creating anything in the tenant.

This site belongs to a Microsoft 365 group. To delete the site, you must delete the group.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MAG8.png)

Below are some attempts:

```
 #Modules
 Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
 Import-Module Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell
 Import-Module SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline
        
 $site = "https://tenant.sharepoint.com/sites/site"
 $mailGroup = "group@onmicrosoft.com"
        
 #First
 Remove-UnifiedGroup -Identity $mailGroup-Confirm:$false
 Remove-SPOSite -Identity $site -NoWait -Confirm:$false
        
 #Second
 Remove-UnifiedGroup -Identity $mailGroup-Confirm:$false
        
 Set-SPOSite -Identity $site  -LockState "unlock" 
 Set-SPOSite -Identity $site  -Owner $userCredential.UserName
 Remove-SPOSite -Identity $site -NoWait -Confirm:$false
        
 #Third
 $SharepointSite = Get-SPOSite $site
 Remove-PnPUnifiedGroup -Identity $SharepointSite .GroupID
 Remove-PnPTenantSite $site
```

I also tried what is in the link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/674248/batch-delete-site-collections-in-powershell-from-c.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to run the command `Remove-UnifiedGroup -Identity "group name"` to delete the Microsoft 365 group before run `Remove-SPOSite -Identity $site -NoWait -Confirm:$false`. Note: you may need to wait some time after deleting a group ,then the site can be successfully deleted.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to respond.

Your answer was accurate, I asked the script to wait about 15 minutes after removing the groups, after that I removed the sites and groups from the recycle bin. Then another 15 minutes to recreate these sites, which is about the time to release the Alias ​​of the deleted sites.

Thank you very much!!